# How to use Play Framework WSClient to share the same session to invoke multiple services in Scala?

Tags: scala, rest, session, ws-client

I tried to get more information about WSClient, but did not get enough information on the web.

Here is the scenario: 
I'm invoking 3 different rest services from an application in the following order. Login -> UploadFile -> Submit

I want to share the same session across these 3 rest service calls, to complete my process. I'm able to successfully call the login rest service and when I'm trying to call the remaining services, it is returning the response as **"403 forbidden"**.

I was able to implement the same thing correctly **in Java using** **HttpClient**. But not sure how can I use the same session using WSClient here. How can I solve this issue? or am I getting this issue because of some other reason?

Below is the sample code which I'm using.

```
def login(loginUri: String, userName: String, password: String): Int ={
   val loginResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(loginUri).withAuth(userName, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).get()
   ...
}

def uploadFile(uploadUri: String, file: File): Option[String] ={
   val uploadResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(uploadUri).post(Source(FilePart("file", FilenameUtils.getName(file.getName), Option("application/vnd.ms-excel"), FileIO.fromPath(file.toPath)) :: List()))
   ...
}

def invoke(uri: String, payload: String): Option[String] {
   val futResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(uri).addHttpHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").post(payload)
   ...
}
```

Comment: Guess you need to make sure the session ID/cookie is passed to along all `WSRequest`, as you'd with curl or wget

Comment: hmm.. Let me try that option. Thanks

Comment: I tried passing session id to WSRequest by setting it in a cookie but it is also not working. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: In the query string (e.g. `;JSESSIONID=...`

Comment: That doesn't work too... I'm injecting WSClient using Guice. Even though I pass the session id, it is creating a unique session for each request.

Comment: First make sure it's working with a tool such as `curl` and `wget` then you can think how to reproduce it programmatically

Comment: As I mentioned above it works well in Java. Thanks for your input. I will try some other options as well.